# Versatile variables

Tags: python, variables

I was wondering how to make a variable change accordingly together with another variable:

```
with open(csv_file, 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
    counter = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='myDialect')
    counter = islice(counter, startatline, None)
    totalpendingtosend = sum(1 for row in counter if 'pending' in row)
csvfile.close()

with open(csv_file, 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
    counter = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='myDialect')
    counter = islice(counter, startatline, None)
    totalconfirmedtosend = sum(1 for row in counter if 'confirmed' in row)
csvfile.close()

totaltosend = totalpendingtosend + totalconfirmedtosend
```

In this example I've used the same code twice, because totalpendingtosend and totalconfirmedtosend are hardcoded, but is there a way that by using the line:

```
statuses = ['confirmed', 'pending']
for i in statuses:
    with open(csv_file, 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
        counter = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='myDialect')
        counter = islice(counter, startatline, None)
        total_?[i]?_tosend = sum(1 for row in counter if i in row)
    csvfile.close()

    totaltosend += total_?[i]?_tosend
```

That I could somehow also have versatile hardcoded variables change to what is written in the list on top? So changing this: *?[i]?* accordingly basically. Is there a good way to do this, so that I can read out totalpendingtosend and totalconfirmedtosend later on in my code as well?

Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: Side note: when you open a file in a `with` block (context manager) there's no need to `close()` it afterwards. The whole point of `with open(...) as` is to automatically clean up at the end.

Comment: Any time you are tempted to start naming variables dynamically, use a `dict` instead. Start with `total_items_to_send = {}` and at your ??? line use `total_items_to_send[i]`. Alternately, use a function to dedupe your code: `total_pending_to_send = how_many_to_send('pending', startatline); total_confirmed_to_send = how_many_to_send('confirmed', startatline)`

Comment: great suggestions above. You might also want to swap `with` and `for` to avoid iterating the file twice. More extreme suggestion is to use pandas, then the whole example would be a one liner.

Comment: Thanks @Amadan. I haven't really experienced the full potential of dictonaries, so I used a simple list, with a for loop and conditional statements changing the needed variables.

Comment: @Marat, I don't really understand what you mean by swapping `for` and `with`, and what it does in changing my code. I have updated the solution I used, containing `for` and `with` statements as well. If you have the time pointing out if the problem with itereration still remains, I'd be glad. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks @Chris for pointing this out, I added all .close()'s to my code later on just in case it went wrong somewhere, but this helps now that it's actually not needed in these cases.

Answer (score 0):

I had to update the code a bit to get the wanted result, which has nothing to do with the question. But at least this is the complete code if anyone else needs this.

```
statuses = ['confirmed', 'pending']
totalconfirmedtosend, totalpendingtosend = 0, 0

for i in statuses:
    with open(csv_file, 'r', newline= '' ) as csvfile:
        counter = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='myDialect')
        counter = islice(counter, startatline, None)

        for row in counter:
            ordernummer = (row[0] if not '.' in row[0] else row[0].split('.')[0]).strip()

            if i in row:
                with open('Sentalready_' + i + '.txt') as file:
                    alreadysent = False
                    l = []

                    for line in file:
                        alreadysent = line[:-1] == ordernummer
                        l.append(alreadysent)

                    ## Answer:
                    if i is 'confirmed':
                        if not any(l) == True:
                            totalconfirmedtosend += 1

                    elif i is 'pending':
                        if not any(l) == True:
                            totalpendingtosend += 1
```

As you can see what I did was pretty sipmle. Using conditions within the for loop did the trick. I'm wondering if this is the best way, but at least it cut my code in half and I can add more statuses pretty easily. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score -2):

### Original answer

<del>Yes, there is a way.  But you don't want to use it.</del>

<del>You can use `locals` to do what you want, the way you want.  But that way is not Pythonic.</del>

<del>The code would be as ugly as this:</del>

```
locals()["total_%s_tosend" % i] = sum(1 for row in counter if i in row)
```

<del>`locals` returns a dictionary that represents the local variables in the context it is run.  You can read them, you can write them, you can create new local variables altogether programmatically.</del>

<del>But that is really, really, really ugly, and you should not do that.</del> Instead, do as @Amadan said: use a dictionary.

PS: did I mention you should not use this answer?

## Update

The answer above is wrong. I stand corrected, and I have learned something new:

[Writing to locals() works in contrast to documentation saying its not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44357111/writing-to-locals-works-in-contrast-to-documentation-saying-its-not) (no it doesn't.  Not necessarily, at least...)

Thanks @user2357112 for pointing that out.  I'll leave the answer here so others learn from my mistake :)

Comment: "You can read them, you can write them, you can create new local variables altogether programmatically." - nope. Modifying `locals()` is unsupported, and [fails in a function](http://ideone.com/J6y6v8) in current CPython.

Comment: Thanks, @user.  Answer updated to reflect my new knowledge :)